# Javascript - How to clear context data?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, line, stroke

How do I empty the data in my `ctx`?

Basically the second `stroke()` should do anything, but draws another triangle. How do I clear this triangle from `ctx`?

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.save();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(20, 20);
ctx.lineTo(20, 100);
ctx.lineTo(70, 100);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();

ctx.stroke();//First stroke
ctx.restore();//Does not empty line paths?

ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
ctx.stroke();//Seccond stroke, same triangle drawn, but green (I do not want to draw the triangle)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dh3e5wg6/

Comment: Read the description of `restore`: it is not intended to clear the canvas, but the settings.

Comment: I'm not trying to clear the canvas, I'm trying to clear the `ctx` properties, so when I do my second `stroke()`, nothing should happen

Comment: `restore` does not wipe out the memory of what is the "current" path. Use `beginPath` for that.

Comment: So how do I wipe the "current" path?

Comment: Even if I'm doing `rect()` right after ?

Comment: A `rect` creates a new path any way.

Comment: In my program it didn't. I had to put `beginPath` for it to clear before `rect`, the reason why I asked this question